# why cannot i delete Linkedlist Node?

Tags: c++

I want to create linkedList from Arraylist. I use new curNode and give value, but when I want to delete it after use it, it's wrong. why cannot i  delete curNode?

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
};

ListNode *addListNode(int* arr,int n){
    ListNode *head=NULL,*curNode,*tail;
    for(int index=0;index!=n;++index){
        curNode = new ListNode(arr[index]);
        if (head==NULL)
            head=curNode;
        else
            tail->next=curNode;
        tail = curNode;
        //delete curNode;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, it's wrong? What happens?

Comment: Doing the delete you're deleting the node you just created (release the memory under the pointer curNode, so also under head/tail). You can delete the node when you remove it from the List.

Comment: your are deleting your node in java you can go with iterator and remove the iterator

Comment: Since you're storing the pointer, you're not done using it, so you shouldn't delete anything. (And it's "array", not "ArrayList".)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you're assigning pointers and not the values: `head=curNode;`, `tail->next=curNode;`, `tail = curNode;`.
So you shouldn't delete the same pointer as it will free the memory which your new created ListNode elements are pointing to.

You should delete the allocated memory after using the returned ListNode or better in the ListNode destructor. Also consider using smart pointers (e.g. `std::unique_ptr<ListNode>`) to be sure that the allocated memory will be automatically freed when it is not used anymore.